# remove sequence of line feeds and spaces in file with sed

Tags: replace, sed, cmd

I have a [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tamo0gplyr6eccy/problem.rpt?dl=0) wich contains an undesired sequence of line feeds and spaces that I want to remove. The actual file is about 1 million rows, this is just to provide a reproducible example.

I can `grep` the offending lines like this:

```
grep -ciP "\n\n {6,}" problem.rpt
```

And it correctly returns

```
## 3
```

So I tried with `sed` to replace the string:

```
sed "s/\n\n {6,}//g" problem.rpt > prob2.rpt
```

but instead of deleting the sequence `"\n\n {6,}"` I now have `"\r\n\r\n {6,}"` (it introduced a CR *before* each LF, without removing it or the 6+ spaces).

I'm working with GNU `sed` and `grep` in a windows 8.1 `cmd`.

What am I doing wrong, and what's the right way to approach this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a list of `sed` one-liners I found one command that solved my problem:

```
sed -e :a -e "$!N; s/\n //;ta" -e "P;D" problem.rpt > prob2.rpt
```

Then, trying to decipher the command, this is what I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461191/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-in-a-sed-command) (copied verbatim):

```
sed ':a;  $!N;  s/\n/string/;  ta'
     ---  ----  -------------  --
      |     |        |          |--> go back (`t`) to `a`
      |     |        |-------------> substitute newlines with `string`
      |     |----------------------> If this is not the last line (`$!`), append the 
      |                              next line to the pattern space.
      |----------------------------> Create the label `a`.
```

I still don't know what the `P;D` part does, I'd appreciate if someone with the knowledge edits this answer to add it.

Answer (score 0):

does one of the followings help you? Very likely the 2nd one is what you are looking for:

```
awk -v RS="\n\n {6,}" '7' problem.rpt

awk -v RS="\n\n {6,}" -v ORS="" '7' problem.rpt
```

I think you have gawk too, right?

I don't have windows to test for you....

Comment: Both lines complain because of the singe quote around the 7, so I changed them to double quotes. After that: The first line produces a file identical to the one I produced with my `sed` command. The second produces an almost identical file, except that it lacks the *last* set of CRLF at the end of file (original file only has LF, files created with your line number 1 and sed have CRLF)